# ubuntu - You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost, virtualbox

I installed ubuntu server 12.04 and used windows 7 folder as shared folder using guestadditions.  I can see the folder as sf__projects, so i symlinked it to var/www/_projects

But the issue is all folders have user root assigned to them. I tried so many options from different blogs but nothing works.

This is what I am getting on apache error log:

```
[Tue Jul 17 17:43:27 2012] [crit] [client 192.168.0.108] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/_projects/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

screenshot of folders: [`http://www.diigo.com/item/image/80d3/d3ha`]

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       bab.local   www.bab.local
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/bab

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin emailxxx@gmail.com

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/_projects/bab/master"

    ServerName bab.local
    ServerAlias www.bab.local

    ErrorLog /var/www/_projects/bab/master/var/logs/apache_error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/_projects/bab/master/var/logs/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/_projects/bab/master/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

my windows host file:

```
192.168.0.79    bab.local   www.bab.local
```

when i try to access site through browser, i get:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I am exactly not sure why it's trying to access: **var/www/_projects/.htaccess**

NOTE:
192.168.0.79 is ubuntu's ip
192.168.0.108 windows ip

Has anyone experienced this and fixed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's trying to read the `.htaccess` file because it's there.  Your httpd (apache) is set to read the filename set in the `AccessFileName` directive and you have `AllowOverride All`.  If you don't need the settings in the `.htaccess` file then you can just delete that file.
2. It can't read the `.htaccess` file because only `root` and `vboxsf` can read/write from/to it.  Your `httpd` is probably running as `www-data` since you're on Ubuntu 12.04.  Check your `httpd` configuration which `User` it is running as.  <strike>You can add an entry in your `/etc/fstab` for your VirtualBox shared folder to set the `uid` (and `gid`) when mounting it.</strike>  Looks like you can't rely on fstab to successfully mount the volume on boot because, apparently, fstab gets read before the sf (sharedfolder) module gets loaded so you should use the `mount` command in `/etc/rc.local` if you want it to mount automatically (https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15868).
3. Same thing with '/'; only `root` and `vboxsf` can read it.